# Only show tasks from the current desktop on Plasma

Tags: kde, plasma-5

In old versions, the **Task Manager > Settings** screen (context menu option on the task manager) had an option **Only show tasks from the current desktop**.

When I upgraded from 16.04 to 17.10, that option disappeared and the Task Manager is now showing windows from all desktops. How do I set it back to only showing the current desktop's windows in the task manager?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Right click on any task in the taskbar.
Left click on Task Manager Settings...
Scroll to the bottom of the first tab called General
The second option under Filters is Show only tasks from the current desktop. Click this.
Click Apply button
Click Ok button

Comment: Found it, thanks... I'd looked there before but I guess it was hidden by a not very noticeable scrollbar.

Comment: Agreed. Not at all obvious scrollbar. Fooled me also.

Comment: Thanks, working on MX Linux 19 Plasma Desktop